Why do some people pronounce "familiar" with an /ɚ/ in the first syllable?
In American English, the word familiar is normally pronounced as /fəˈmɪl.jɚ/. Recently, though, I've noticed more people pronouncing it as /fɚˈmɪl.jɚ/ ("fermiliar"), an alternate pronunciation listed on Wiktionary. Looking through YouGlish, this seems to be uncommon, but certainly well-attested; for some examples of this pronunciation, see this video at 6:55 or this video at 0:15.
So: how did this unusual pronunciation come about? Is it a general process, or something specific to this one word?

A kind of “intrusive r”?

AmE becoming more rhotic?

It's probably an assimilation to the /r/ (or /ɚ/) later in the word. Nancy Hall's paper "R-Dissimilation in English" (2007), which I have cited a few times previously*, discusses this, saying

Resonances can also cause listeners to err on the side of perceiving too many /r/s, and this produces colloquial insertion of /r/ in words already containing an /r/, such as farmiliar, perservere, and sherbert.

(p. 1)
See pages 19-21 for more discussion and examples.

*In 'Forward' pronounced more often as 'foward'?, Pronunciation of 'Arguable'

Thanks for finding this! I've definitely heard that pronunciation of persevere, and I myself pronounce sherbet with an extra /ɚ/.
